# flask script file structure

Tags: python, flask, flask-script

what does "python manage.py runserver" runs in situation below. It does not run main.py or app package.

**flask**

```
myApp          
    main.py
```

`bash> python main.py`

**flask_script**

```
manage.py
myApp
    __init__.py
    main.py
```

`bash> python manage.py runserver`

**manage.py**

```
from flask_script import Manager
from myApp import app

manager = Manager(app)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager.run()
```

**main.py**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)  

@app.route('/')
def hello():   
    return "Hello World"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and `__init__.py` is empty

Comment: Please feel free to explain what is wrong with my way of questioning.

Comment: Giving minuses with no explanation makes communication in this community very difficult and frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own questions since i get arbitrary minuses whenever i ask anything in this warm and welcoming community.

I found "a way" maybe not "the way".

**file structure**

```
|manage.py
|myApp
  |__init__.py
  |main.py
  |blog
    |__init__.py
    |blog.py
```

**manage.py**

```
from flask_script import Manager
from flask import Flask

from myApp.main import interface as main_inaterface
from myApp.blog.blog import interface as blog_interface

app.register_bluprint(main_interface, url_prefix='/main')
app.register_bluprint(blog_interface, url_prefix='/blog')

manager = Manager(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

**myApp.__ init __.py**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

import myApp
```

**main.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint

interface = Blueprint('myApp', __name__)

@interface.route('/')
def hello():
    return "from main"
```

**blog**

```
from flask import Blueprint

interface = Blueprint('blog', __name__)

@interface.route('/')
def blog():
  return "From Blog"
```